# Gravity form with paypal adon should return custom receipt

Tags: forms, plugin-gravity-forms, paypal

One of the websites that I work with has a booking form created by Gravity form and it's PayPal pro add-on. Currently, when someone books something, PayPal send a default receipt. How can I get PayPal to send a custom receipt that includes more information from the booking form?

Answer (score 0):

The receipt needs to be generated from within Gravity Forms. You cannot include Gravity Forms’ fields inside PayPal receipts/emails.

Create the receipt as an email notification for the form submitter, and use conditional logic to only send that notification when the payment is successful.

Comment: Hi, It actually sends a booking notice (not receipt) to the company, not the customers. Currently, that booking notice from Paypal includes an email, first and last name. But there are many other fields we collect from gravity form. Is there a way to add them into this booking notice?